# Need to display \r\n in entry box Python Tkinter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a program where i need to display in an entry box the \r\n characters. However in this entry box in tkinter they don't show up. When I send and return over serial, the \r\n shows up on what is returned so the characters are there, they're just not being displayed.

Is there any way to get these characters to show up in the entry box without having to manually enter them each time.

Here is the code

```
from tkinter import *


title_str = "Entry Boxes Test"

root = Tk()
root.title(title_str)

f1_value = StringVar()
f1_value.set("=> HELP\r\n")
f2_value = StringVar()
f2_value.set("=> VERSION\r\n")


def callback_f1():
    listbox.insert(END,  f1_entry.get())
    listbox.see(END)
    return


def callback_f2():
    listbox.insert(END,  f2_entry.get())
    listbox.see(END)
    return

title_frame = Frame(root)
title_frame.pack(side=TOP)

body_frame = Frame(root)
body_frame.pack(side=TOP)

left = Frame(body_frame)
right = Frame(body_frame)
left.pack(side=LEFT)
right.pack(side=LEFT)

bottom_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=TOP)

#attach scroll bar to bottom frame for messages
scrollbar = Scrollbar(bottom_frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(bottom_frame, width=40)
listbox.pack()

# attach listbox to scrollbar
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

title_var = StringVar()
title = Label(title_frame, textvariable=title_var, relief=FLAT, height=2)
title_var.set(title_str)
title.pack(side=TOP)

#F1 and F2
f1_button = Button(left, text="F1", width=15, height=2, command=callback_f1, state=NORMAL)
f1_button.pack(side=TOP)
f1_entry = Entry(left, textvariable=f1_value, width=18)
f1_entry.pack(side=TOP)
f2_button = Button(right, text="F2", width=15, height=2, command=callback_f2, state=NORMAL)
f2_button.pack(side=TOP)
f2_entry = Entry(right, textvariable=f2_value, width=18)
f2_entry.pack(side=TOP)


root.mainloop()
```

I've tried separating it like

```
f1_value.set("=> Help" + "\r\n")
```

and

```
f1_value.set("=> FUP{ret}".format(ret="\r\n"))
```

but nothings worked so far.

Thanks in advance!

Sending this over serial,

```
ser = serial.Serial()
def write_ser(st):
    ser.write(st.encode())
    time.sleep(1)
    while ser.inWaiting():
        try:
            s = ser.read(20)
        except:
            listbox.insert(END, "read failed")
            listbox.see(END)
            return
        listbox.insert(END,  "<" + str(s)[2:-1] + ">")
        listbox.see(END)
    return
```

with, e.g. for f1,

```
def callback_f1():
    listbox.insert(END,  f1_entry.get())
    listbox.see(END)
    write_ser(f1_entry.get())
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to display `\` literally, escape them:

```
f1_value = StringVar()
f1_value.set("=> HELP\\r\\n")
f2_value = StringVar()
f2_value.set("=> VERSION\\r\\n")
```

or use `r'raw string literals'`:

```
f1_value = StringVar()
f1_value.set(r"=> HELP\r\n")
f2_value = StringVar()
f2_value.set(r"=> VERSION\r\n")
```

Comment: Thanks champ!
It was the second one.
But now when it comes back over the serial port, it returns with double \ as in: 
"=> HELP\\r\\n"
Any way to display it as "=> HELP\r\n" and get that back too?

Comment: @Boonnny, I don't get what you mean. Try to print the data from the serial port: `print(data_from_serial_port)`. What do you see?

Comment: So it's being sent over over bluetooth through a USB to serial COM port, I've added that code into the question. When it gets mirrored back, I get e,g, "=> HELP\\r\\n"
I want what its sending to just be "=> HELP\r\n" and also that to be displayed so other people can easily change this but still see what was there originally, and what they're changing.

I hope I'm explaining this ok.

Comment: @Boonnny, Try `s = ser.read(20).replace('\n', r'\n').replace('\r', r'\r')` or `s = ser.read(20).replace(r'\n', '\n').replace(r'\r', '\r')`.